# Problem to prove function is convex or not?

Tags: convex-optimization

How do I plot function $f(x1,x2)=x^4_1+x^4_2$ such that $x^2_1+x^2_2=1$ and $x_1,x_2\in(0,1)$?
Does it possible to plot in MATLAB so that I can visualize the function?

Also I am trying to check whether $f$ is convex or not, because I am trying to optimize it and accordingly formulate the problem like that

Maximize $x^{4}_1+x^{4}_2+\cdots+x^{4}_n$

Subject to

$x^{2}_1+x^{2}_2+\cdots+x^{2}_n=1$

$x_i\in(0,1)$, $i=\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$

And I calculate its Hessian matrix:
$$
H=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 12x^{2}_1 & 0  \\ 
 0 &  12x^{2}_2
 \end{array}\right]
$$

After that I don't know how to proceed. Can anyone help me to prove whether f is convex or not?

Thank you very much.

Comment: $f$ (twice differentiable) is convex if and only if its hessian is positive semidefinite, that is exactly the case if every eigenvalues are non-negative. What are the eigenvalues of $H$? Apart from your question, you are maximizing a convex function on a non convex set ... are you sure?

Comment: This is not a convex optimization model. The Hessian is indeed a convex *function*; however, you are maximizing it, and that is nonconvex. Furthermore, nonlinear equality constraints are (with very few manufactured exceptions) not convex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "convex" is a bit overloaded. In this single problem alone it needs to be used to ask three different questions:

1. Is this *function* convex?
2. Is this *set* convex?
3. Is this *optimization model* convex?

These questions are not the same, and one does not necessarily imply the others.

Your *function* $f$ is convex. That is easily verified, as you have done, by examining the Hessian.

Your *constraint set* $\left\{x\in(0,1)^n\,\middle|\,\sum_i x_i^2=1\right\}$ is *not* convex. Nonlinear equality constraints are almost never convex. This set describes the positive quadrant of the unit hypersphere, and this is not convex. Indeed, take *any* distinct pair of points in the set; their midpoint is not in the set (a necessary condition for convexity).

Finally, a *convex optimization* model requires that:

- Minimization of a convex function, or maximization of a concave function.
- Each and every constraint describes a convex set.

Your model fails both tests, because you are *maximizing* a convex function, and your nonlinear equality constraint is not convex.

EDIT: I should add that you could relax your constraint to $\left\{x\in(0,1)^n\,\middle|\,\sum_i x_i^2\leq 1\right\}$ without changing the optimal value of the problem. This would make your constraint set convex; but it would still be a nonconvex optimization problem, due to your attempt to maximize a convex function.

*All that said*, this problem is not that difficult to solve. In order to make the optimum achievable we need to relax the constraints to $\left\{x\in[0,1]^n\,\middle|\,\sum_i x_i^2\leq 1\right\}$ (i.e., non-strict inequalities on $x$). In that case, the optimal value is 1, and the optimal points are all of the unit vectors with a single non-zero value of $1$.